# openid connect for drupal tutorial

Tags: drupal, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

Here is the senario. I am trying to create a drupal 7 site that will serve as my openid connect server for another site that is being created in python. We want to have single sign on for the python site so that user will be synchronized between both the drupal site and the python site.

Question:

Does anyone know of a step by step tutorial (or can you tell me how) to setup a drupal site to do this?

I don't know anything about drupal and I am having a very difficult time trying to get the openid connect module properly configured to allow sso. I think I have successfully installed the openid connect, openid connect sso, and oauth 2 modules as well as the oauth2_server_php library.

Where I am stuck:

1. when I go into the oauth2 settings, the "Use openid connect" check field is not present. According to one tutorial I have seen, it's supposed to be there.
2. When you configure openid connect, the 3 url endpoints (Authorization endpoint, Token endpoint and UserInfo endpoint) are a mystery to me and I don't know what to put in them. Right now my drupal server is running on my local host webserver. "http://localhost/drupal"

Answer (score 2):

So you are basically trying to implement the OpenID connect protocol and then use that from a python based website. I guess you already have googled that and trying to implement your own.

And the second portion is how will your python website use this newly created openid connect implementation.

We already have an openid connect implementation and also a step by step guide for sites wanting to use it.

If you want to consider an alternate, We have a step by step guide with sample code in Java as well as PHP on how to use miniOrange as your OpenID connect provider, [here](http://miniorange.com/openid-connect).

SO this guide will take care of your "another site in python".

Python samples are being added as we speak so stay tuned or ping me if you are interested.